# Problem with initDirectFieldAccess in Spring controller method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, caching, controller

I am seeing a really wierd behaviour. I have a Spring controller method that take as a single parameter a JavaBean object that has validation annotations and an initBinder method to allow
initDirectFieldAccess. The code is like the next:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {    
    binder.initDirectFieldAccess(); 
    log.info("ending initBinder");  
}




@PostMapping    
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<OpValidateResponse> validateClient(
        @RequestBody @Valid OpValidateRequest request) {
    log.info("Beginning execution of method");
    final OpValidateResponse response = validateClientService
            .validateClient(sanitizeXSSForObject(request));
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(response);
}
```

The wierd thing is that between the logging `"ending initBinder"` in initBinder method and the logging `"Beginning execution of method"` of validateClient method takes just the first time the method is called between 6-10 seconds but the next executions just not. If I comment the line "binder.initDirectFieldAccess(); ", there is almost no time between those methods ever.

1. So, may be the reflection the cause because of the sentence     `binder.initDirectFieldAccess();` that is too slow the first time?
2. Why the next times takes almost no time between the methods? Some kind of caching?

Thanks

Comment: After enabling direct field access the first time a map of fields/bindings is being build using reflection. After that it is cached, so the first time the binding takes place takes longer... You could of course have checked this for yourself in the source code (it is open source)....

Comment: But the wierd thing is that the first time it takes 6-10 seconds

Comment: I explained that that is due to the reflection being done to do the binding, after that it is cached.

Comment: Yes, I understand but its wierd it takes 6-10 seconds

Comment: Again no it isn't and how long it takes also depends on the size of your object, the more fields the longer it will take. Reflection is, relatively, slow.